# How can I get the raw request body in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need the raw request body to be able to SHA-1 digest it to validate the Facebook webhook X-Hub-Signature header that's passed along with the request to my Firebase Function (running on Google Cloud Functions).

The problem is that in cases like this (with a `Content-Type: application/json` header) GCF automatically parses the body using `bodyParser.json()` which consumes the data from the stream (meaning it cannot be consumed again down the Express middleware chain) and only provides the parsed javascript object as `req.body`. The raw request buffer is discarded.

I have tried to provide an Express app to `functions.https.onRequest()`, but that seems to be run as a child app or something with the request body already being parsed, just like when you pass a plain request-response callback to `onRequest()`.

Is there any way to disable GCF from parsing the body for me? Or could I somehow specify my own `verify` callback to `bodyParser.json()`? Or is there some other way?

PS: I first contacted Firebase support about this a week ago, but for lack of a response there I'm trying it here now.

Comment: I am in the same situation as you. I tried to "regenerate" the raw request payload but it's not feasible. A security workaround is to deploy the function with random characters so that the endpoint is unguessable. I elaborate more in my article [here](https://medium.com/@mrkevinze/regenerating-a-raw-request-payload-an-impossible-task-e4133fb2571)

Comment: Now you can get the raw body from req.rawBody.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Now you can get the raw body from `req.rawBody`. It returns `Buffer`. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests) for more details.

Thanks to Nobuhito Kurose for posting this in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950561/how-can-i-get-the-raw-request-body-in-a-google-cloud-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#comment82543207_42950561).

Comment: Typescript will recognize rawBody if it's imported from `functions.https.Request`, but it will not recognize the field if it is imported from `functions.Request`

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the default middleware currently provides no way to get the raw request body. See: [Access to unparsed JSON body in HTTP Functions (#36252545)](https://issuetracker.google.com/36252545).

Comment: That's too bad. I starred that issue and hope some form of support for this will be added soon. This might cause us to switch back partially or completely to Amazon, but I really rather enjoyed Firebase up till so far.
Thanks for the info and link!

Comment: There's been discussion (beyond the public ticket) and several Googlers, including myself, are feeling pain from this. I can't commit to timeline but this has to be fixed as web-hooks are one of our critical stories. It just didn't make the cut for beta unforuntately.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const escapeHtml = require('escape-html');

/**
 * Responds to an HTTP request using data from the request body parsed according
 * to the "content-type" header.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.helloContent = (req, res) => {
  let name;

  switch (req.get('content-type')) {
    // '{"name":"John"}'
    case 'application/json':
      ({name} = req.body);
      break;

    // 'John', stored in a Buffer
    case 'application/octet-stream':
      name = req.body.toString(); // Convert buffer to a string
      break;

    // 'John'
    case 'text/plain':
      name = req.body;
      break;

    // 'name=John' in the body of a POST request (not the URL)
    case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
      ({name} = req.body);
      break;
  }

  res.status(200).send(`Hello ${escapeHtml(name || 'World')}!`);
};
```

Comment: Hi, you may want to give explanation too along with your code to be a bit more clear