# Firebase functions parsing request body before I can handle it in Express

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to handle invalid requests in Firebase functions, so making a post request with invalid JSON, with the intent of handling it in express. but I get **400 error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 20'** before it even reaches express layer, and the worst thing is the function runs for 60 seconds untill it hits timeout error.

my function

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();


const app = express();

app.use((err: any, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  res.json({ error: 'invalid request' });
  next(err);
});

app.post('/test', (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.json({ error: 'invalid request' });
  res.end();
  return;
});



const server = functions.runWith({ maxInstances: 100 }).https.onRequest(app);

export { server as api };
```

the invalid json,

```
{
    "es":"adfasdf"asdf
}
```

I suspect this has something to do with the https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request at "This parsing is done by the following body parsers:"

Comment: Try changing the import to `import express from 'express';`

Comment: @Dharmaraj Same error, besides docs explicitly say data would be parsed by 'jsonParser' if content-type is '"Content-Type:application/json" then the 'Sent data would be materialized under ...etc', check the link I mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase Functions are built on top of the [`functions-framework-nodejs`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) package (or at least, an internal variant of the same code).

[Within that package](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/78ba5c1b287e1efbb2f48672b667547eeb1de165/src/server.ts#L91-L95), the body parsers you mention are injected. As you correctly surmised, these are indeed added before your code even [gets the chance to execute](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/78ba5c1b287e1efbb2f48672b667547eeb1de165/src/server.ts#L136-L142).

As the error is internal to Firebase's operations, you will need to reach out to [Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).