# Is request.rawBody a buffer? I'm confused on defining 'buf'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, buffer

I'm following the code here: https://kiewic.com/validate-x-hub-signatue for validating a header's signature and I think I have it all correct and understood besides 'buf'. I've never heard of a buffer and through some research I think (?) I've concluded that request.rawBody is what should be the argument but I'm not confident.

```
// Sends the post body into the db and the header is used to validate the post
exports.addEvent = functions.https.onRequest((request, resolve) => {
    if (request.method !== "POST") {
        resolve.status(400).send('Please send a POST request')
        return
    }
    //This checks if the request is valid
    if (!verifyRequest(request, request.rawBody)) {
```

Is request.rawBody the correct argument? ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ as 'buf'

```
        resolve.status(400).send('Please send a valid request')
        return
    }
    // adds post body to the db
    fb.db.collection("fbCollectionToAddTo").add(request.body)
    return
})



  // Calculate the Signature header value. 
    function getSignature(buf) {
        var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha1", "SECRETSTRING")
        hmac.update(buf, "utf-8")
        return "sha1=" + hmac.digest("hex")
    }

    // Verifies that the signature is correct
    function verifyRequest(req, buf) {
        var expected = req.headers['Signature']
        var calculated = getSignature(buf)
        console.log("Signature:", expected, "Content:", "-" + buf.toString('utf8') + "-")
        if (expected !== calculated) {
            console.log("Invalid signature.")
            return false
        } else {
            console.log("Valid signature!")
            return true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Cloud Functions [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_content_types) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950561/how-can-i-get-the-raw-request-body-in-a-google-cloud-function), `request.rawBody` is, in fact a buffer that contains the entire body of the request.  Whether or not that's correct for your specific case, I don't know.  If `verifyRequest` expects to get the rest body as its second argument, then yes, looks OK.

Comment: This is in the documentation for the code I linked: where buf is a Buffer of the raw request body ...

This is making me confused because buf isn't a buffer of the raw request body, it *IS* the raw request body?...

Comment: It contains the data, sure.

Comment: My question is basically how do I make request.rawBody a Buffer? As it says "buf is a Buffer of the raw request body.." This wording wouldn't make sense if request.rawBody is already a Buffer.. Maybe I am just over complicating it?

Comment: It is a buffer.  That should be clear from my answer?  Are you observing something different?  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: Ah. It's making sense now. I wasn't understanding what a buffer was and now I do. Thank you!